# Meaning of “se checker”

Tags: sens

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

> Ça y est, nous avons reglé nos comptes, on peut se checker maintenant.

Context: a neighborhood gang leader has blown up the car of a guy which lives in the neighborhood as punishment because the guy had refused to make him a favor. They meet in the next day in a building and the gangster says the sentence above.

https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/checker/ says that "checker" is an anglicanism which means "to check". However, nobody says "we can check ourselves now" in English, so I assume that this expression is a French-specific slang. What does it mean?

Comment: See [Urban Dictionary entry](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=check%20yo%20self). Without further context I would understand it as: "We got even, now we can lie low / back off (lest we attract more attention and face consequences)." Actually not a huge leap from the fourth definition under "verb" https://wiktionary.org/wiki/check, except slangified. This is not an answer just in case a native speaker comes to say that the meaning has indeed shifted since the borrowing.

Comment: I leave the above as a case study in a theory being logical yet wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the meaning is to bump hands, often with personal variants depending on who is doing it, to salute someone: *faire un check*.

See https://www.francetvinfo.fr/monde/comment-le-check-s-est-impose-dans-la-vie-de-tous-les-jours_877483.html

I believe this is called a fist bump in English.

The origin of the noun/verb *check* might be an assimilation with *(hand)shake*, as *shake* and *check* are often pronounced identically (/tʃɛk/) by French people while *faire un shake* (pronounced /ʃɛk/) would collide with *faire un chèque* ("write/cut a cheque").

Comment: Watching again the scene, I have noticed that the gangster closes one of his hands and puts it forward in a fist bump position, so I think you have hit the nail on the head. Thanks!

Comment: nitpicking, though: a check traditionally starts with slapping palms, hands open, and then there's a fist bump. There are tons of variations on this simple model, including double-slap without fist bump, or skipping directly to the first bump.